# How can I stengthen the durability of my newly installed engineered hardwood floor?

Tags: flooring

I have new engineered hardwood floors, *Santamaria Hardwood Flooring*. The veneer is very thin. Before I move in the furniture, I would like to apply polyurethane on my new floors. Can I simply apply a product on the floors as is? In otherwords do I need to prep? If so, what is the process?

Additionally, for this particular job, is one product better than another and what tools will be needed,.

Comment: I copy and pasted "Santamaria Hardwood Flooring" in a google search. I came up with no results, nothing to go by on your floor at least, plenty on flooring contractors in Santa Maria CA

Comment: Is there a finish on the floor now?

Answer (score 1):

Engineered hardwoord are almost always prefinished.  And the factory aluminum oxide coating is harder than anything you can do at home so there is no reason to re-do the existing coating.

Answer (score 0):

I have engineered hardwood with a thin veneer of maple. The wood layer wore off in heavily used areas. It get scratches easily from my dogs. The factory coating is not sufficient on my engineered wood. I read it is best to apply polyurethane about 2-3 times over the engineered wood. That way it also seals the gaps in between boards. It does make it less likely to scratch or wear off.